# How to get Paypal transactions in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, paypal, transactions

**Problem description:**

I go into my paypal buyer sandbox account and send 10 Pounds to my facilitator sandbox account. The transaction goes trough and all is fine. I log into my facilitator account and i see the transaction.

Now when i use the following nodejs code to get the transactions:

```
var paypal_api = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

var config_opts = {
    'host': 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    'port': '',
    'client_id': 'HIDDEN',
    'client_secret': 'HIDDEN'
};


var listPayment = {
    'count': '10',
    'start_index': '0'
};

paypal_api.payment.list(listPayment, config_opts, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("List Payments Response");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
    }
});
```

i get this in the console:

```
List Payments Response
{"count":0,"httpStatusCode":200}
```

So its not showing me any transactions.

How can i see those transactions?

I have read on another Stackoverflow thread that **these might not show up** because **they are not done trough REST**. If thats the case, would payments done trough the official PayPal mobile app appear in my NodeJS response?

**Question 2:**

Is there any way by using NodeJS to see transactions that are coming into my merchant account? (paid in from the PayPal app, or from their website)

**Question 3:**

How can i use WebHooks to see the transactions in NodeJS?

I would really appreciate your help guys, ive been looking everywhere for a response to these questions.

Thank you so much.

Alex

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried **Webhooks** and i still cant get anything to trigger when i do a transaction. **An event triggers** on my NodeJS side **only when i use the Webhook simulator**, but not when i do a normal transaction on Paypal using my sandbox accounts.

I wonder if there is any way to test things with the Paypal mobile app, does anybody know if you can do sandbox testing with the mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

Click manage webhooks and Add your webhook listener URL(API endpoint), then select which event you want to get from PayPal.

[image: img]